# How to get libicui18n.so.36 ?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I try to install PyICU but it require libicui18n.so.36
I dont know How to get it could you help me please...

Answer (score 5):

If you are on Ubuntu, try installing the `python-pyicu` package, which should take care of any binary dependencies, instead of trying to install from the sources:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pyicu
```

Alternatively, if you really need to install from the source package (e.g. with `pip install pyicu`), you'll need to the `libicu` development package installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libicu-dev
```